# Why does Java not show an error for double semicolon at the end of a statement?

Tags: java, java-compiler-api

I accidentally wrote a java statement with two semicolons at the end.  The java compiler does not show any error and it runs.

Code:

```
System.out.println("Length after delete the text is "+name.length());;
```

For learning purposes I tried adding different characters after the semicolon, and the java compiler has shown the compile time error as **Syntax error on token ")", delete this token**.

This statement:

```
System.out.println("Length after delete the text is "+name.length());)
```

Why does java treat the semicolon and other characters as different?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Because a double semicolon is not treated as a double semicolon but as a semicolon plus an empty statement. And an empty statement, which does nothing, is not an error.

Comment: +1, Exactly, it is very much like writing `{}{}{}{} (braces I mean)` inside your code anywhere.

Comment: Thanks i cleared now. i thing some related points like your answer that is we use semicolon to end the statement But i did not know the second semicolon is a empty operator.

Comment: Actually, it is an empty **statement**. There is no thing like an empty expression in Java.

Comment: Sorry for not using the exact terminology. Corrected.

Comment: Note that you can ask eclipse to flag empty statements with a warning.

Answer (score 18):

As told by other answers, usually the second semicolon is interpreted as an empty statement, which is permissible where ever a statement is permissible.

Actually, there are cases where a double semicolon does produce an error:

```
public int method() {
   return 1;;
}
```

When the compiler determines that a location is not reachable (and this is defined exactly in the JLS, but includes the locations directly after a `return`, `break`, `continue` and `throw`), no statement is allowed there, not even an empty one.

Comment: Another example could be `throw new Exception("xyz");;`

Answer (score 11):

According to the Java language standard, the second semicolon is an [empty statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.6).

> An empty statement does nothing.

```
EmptyStatement:
    ;
```

> Execution of an empty statement always completes normally.

Answer (score 1):

`;` by itself is an empty operator, so you effectively have two operators in the original case.

Comment: Thanks i cleared now. i thing some related points like your answer that is we use semicolon to end the statement But i did not know the second semicolon is a empty operator.

Answer (score 1):

The semicolon ends the sentence.

```
System.out.println("Length after delete the text is "+name.length());;
```

The second semicolon means the sentence is empty.

```
System.out.println("Length after delete the text is "+name.length());)
```

Is wrong because you're trying to finish an uncompleted sentence.